# How to extract all html text excluding what's inside the script tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For a project I want to create a variable that stores all the text within the html, so pretty much everything between tags, titles, paragraphs, everything visible for a user on a webpage. However I don't want my javascript code that's between the script tag to show up in this output too.

I was trying with something like this:

```
var content = $("html").remove("script").text()
```

But this is not working.

Comment: As the [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) says, `remove` actually removes the selector arg from the DOM so here, you are removing the script tags from the DOM but this method doesn't seem to return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

First use this:

```
var r = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

for (var i = (r.length-1); i >= 0; i--) {

    if(r[i].getAttribute('id') != 'a'){
        r[i].parentNode.removeChild(r[i]);
    }

}
```

And then:

```
var txt = document.body.innerText;
```

OR

```
var txt = $('body').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var contentDiv = $('<div/>', {
    html: $('body').clone()
});

contentDiv.find('script').remove()
return contentDiv.text()
```